# Typescript can't compile type not existing Error TS2339

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Hi is there anyone who can help me with the following typescript problem
(I'm completely new to typescript, and I'm trying to convert an old js (not one I have written) file into typescript)

What I have done so far, copy pasted the old js into a new typescript file.
Spend hours trying all different ways to get tsconfig.json to play nice and let me compile the new ts file.
I can see there is a ton of warnings when running the config to strict, and i hope to solve the problems one by one.
But right now I’m stuck by compiling with following Error.

> Error TS2339  (TS) **Property 'ajax' does not exist on type 'typeof
> jQuery** | ((w: any) => typeof jQuery)'.   Property 'ajax' does not
> exist on type 'typeof jQuery'.    Miscellaneous    When calling something
> like this --> jQuery.ajax or **$.ajax** sample.ts 166 Active

In the top of the file, I have the following

```
import * as jQuery from '../Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js';
import * as jcookie from '../Scripts/node_modules/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie';
```

Doesnt matter if I don't rename (as) and just try to use $

I have tried with .js and no .js in the ending of the file.
I can see the exists file in intellisense (And also just by looking in the folder)

a sample of a call that fails
*The code works in pure javascript* (using $ instead of my rename to jQuery)

```
mListHandler.prototype.addm = function () {
    var ref = this;

    ref.ui.jQueryAddmButton.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    jQuery.ajax({
        "url": ref.addmURL,
        "type": "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "error": function () {
            ref.ui.jQueryAddmButton.removeAttr("disabled");
            alert("Server not responding. Unable to save!");
        },
        "success": function (data: any) {
            if (!!data) {                
                jQuery.ajax({
                    "url": appendURL("m?mIDs=" + data), 
                    "type": "POST",
                    "success": function (data: any) {
                        ref.ui.jQuerymTable.append(jQuery("tbody", jQuery(data)).html());                        
                        ref.bindTable();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

My tsconfig.json file looks like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,    
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./AppScript"
  },
  "include": [ "./TSScripts/*.ts" ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try importing the $ like so

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

https://momane.com/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript

I find this helps a lot https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

I hop this helps